# How to create a shortlisting feature in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I want to add a shortlisting feature to my Applications model.

I have a jobs model where each job belongs to an employer and an application model which belongs to a job and a user.
The employer can view responses to his jobs on his dashboard. I want to allow him to shortlist the applications he likes and then view them later or somewhere else in his dashboard.

*It is somewhat similar to the "Add to Cart" feature, but each item added to cart here will belong to a job and an employer, not just the employer.*

I am not able to figure out exactly from where to start. Do I have to create another shortlist model, or add a shortlist boolean attribute to each response, or something else? What will the correct way to go?

I am mainly looking for guidance, prefer not to spoil me with a lot of code :)

NOTE:I am using Rails 4, and Devise for the employer model.

Comment: I would start with adding a `boolean` field named `shortlisted_by_employer` to the `application` model. The "Add to Favorites" button basically just posts to a controller method that updates that boolean attribute to `true`.

Comment: How do I change the value of the boolean when the user clicks the shortlist button?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate table where you add the application id.

Like cart, you can just go to this page and all you get the users which is shorted.

You can create a model like Shortlist for this.

Comment: I feel the boolean migration method to be a bit easier to implement while satisfying the purpose. What are advantages of this method over than one? I don't know, will it trouble me later at scale?

Comment: You mention a cart like system, for this I suggest it. In a boolean system, you cannot track which user shorted application. But if you create a separate table you can track application and who shorted the job both.